# CodeIgniter 2 Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: regex

In `system\core\Input.php`.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[~a-zA-Z0-9{},:_\/-]+$/i', $str))
{

    exit('Disallowed Key Characters: '.$str);
}
```

This triggers Disallowed Key Characters: when `$str` contains:

```
{"education_level":"1","job_experience":"1","occupation":"41-3011","onet_code"
:"41-3011_00","region":"22220","relevance":"0","school":"0","schoolstate":"0","state":"4","gpa":"0","major"
:"0"}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What do I need to change the regex to make $str not fail the regex? I don't see any weird characters in $str.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow also a quote character (`"`) and whitespaces (`\s`). Your regex should be:

```
/^[~a-zA-Z0-9{},:_\/"\s-]+$/i
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC9pI5/1).